# 960 grid's indesign template - pinkish background

Tags: website-design, adobe-indesign, master-page

I am a new InDesign user and in the 960 grids' indesign template there are pinkish backgrounds filling the columns.

-- EDIT -- I am asking that in indesign with which element the pinkish areas are made? I can not select those pinkish boxes, they are not on a sub layer, i can not unlock them, what are they... This is an indesign question... –

Comment: The 960 grid is a CSS framework for web sites. It's not something you'd normally use in InDesign.

Comment: we can use 960 grid templates as a guide when we are designing. In the download folder there are templates for 16 design programs. Your comment is not true i guess.

Comment: you can use whatever guides you want. I'm just pointing out that it's a CSS grid. There's nothing in particular print-centric about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go **download the 960 templates** to see this.... This question is **very specific** to *those* files.

It's just a layer with pink boxes on it to indicate the columns.

[image]

The pink boxes are applied to a master page, then that master page is associated with the locked layer.

Look at the **master pages** you'll find the boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are called the columns, have you tried reading [960.gs](http://960.gs/) to learn more about it?  Here is a [demo](http://960.gs/demo.html).  You can even view [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/nathansmith/960-grid-system).

Your design is based on those columns and there are different options and columns such as 12 column, 24 column, etc. etc.  A good read about it is over at code tuts called [Mastering the 960 Grid System](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-the-960-grid-system--net-13794) that explains how to use them.

If you look at the 960 grid website there are example sites that you can click the show grid button and get an understanding of how the site was designed based on the columns:

[image]

If you're starting out I would encourage you to look into developing in the browser with something like Bootstrap or Foundation because your design would not be responsive.

If you are looking for desktop only I would look into something bigger than 960 such as [1080.gs](http://www.1080.gs)

After clicking the big download button.

- Open the file
- Go to `Window -> Layers`

[image]

[image]

Double click the `12 Grid` layer:

[image]

If you're trying to use CC to open the latest file per the download it says that it is for up to CS5 and its a template file:

[image]

In CC go to the tab `Pages` and double click the `A-Master` white sheet to edit the grid:

[image]